# Shortcut to Google Images, News, More

Tags: google-search, keyboard-shortcuts

I'd like to know if there is a shortcut to go to Google Images, Images, More... A way to navigate between those options like you can go through the results with the UP/DOWN arrows.

Is there something similar to go between those options?

[image: Tabs]

Comment: I don't know of a direct shortcut, but you can `TAB` and `SHIFT`+`TAB` through those elements (like any other page element).

Comment: @w3d yes, that's how I do right now, and that's why i'm asking if there is a direct shortcut... i guess there isn't

Answer (score 1):

Apparently no. I don't think you can migrate between the sites directly using the arrow buttons. You will need to click it manually.